# How can I make tables, matrices, and chemical equations smaller

Tags: formatting

I am looking to make all these things smaller so that they can all fit on the same page. Maybe have 2 lists next to each other but I dont know how to do that

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
\ce{i &-> i + r_I, \\
r_i &-> r_I + I, \\
I + Lac &-> I \cdot Lac, \\
I \cdot Lac &-> I + Lac, \\
I + o &-> I \cdot o, \\
I \cdot o &-> I + o, \\
o + RNAP &-> o \cdot RNAP, \\
o \cdot RNAP &-> o + RNAP, \\
o \cdot RNAP &-> o + RNAP + r, \\
r &-> r + Z, \\
Lac + Z &-> Z, \\
r_I &-> \emptyset, \\
I &-> \emptyset, \\
I \cdot Lac &-> Lac, \\
r &-> \emptyset, \\
z &-> \emptyset
}
\end{align*}

where 


\begin{table}[ht]
%\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Species name & Symbol  \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
%heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
Regulatory gene & $i$ \\ [1ex] % inserting body of the table
Repressor protein & $r_I$ \\ [1ex]
Inhibitor protein & $I$ \\ [1ex]
Lactose & $Lac$ \\ [1ex]
Operator region & $o$ \\ [1ex]
RNA polymerase & $RNAP$ \\ [1ex]
mRNA & $r$ \\ [1ex]
$\beta$-galactosidase & $Z$ \\ [1.5ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\caption{Lac Operon species}
%\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}



Using SPN theory the system is represented as




\[N \, = \, (P,T,\text{Pre},\text{Post},M,h,c), \quad
 P = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
           i \\
           r_I \\
    I \\
    Lac \\
    I \cdot Lac \\
    o \\
    I \cdot o \\
    RNAP \\
    RNAP \cdot o \\
    r \\
    Z \\
         \end{pmatrix}}
%, \quad
% T = \begin{pmatrix}
%       \text{Enzyme-substrate association} \\
%       \text{Enzyme-substrate dissociation} \\
%       \text{Product formation} \\
%     \end{pmatrix}
 \] \\

\[ T = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
       \text{Inhibitor transcription} \\
       \text{Inhibitor translation} \\
       \text{Lactose inhibitor binding} \\
    \text{Lactose inhibitor dissociation} \\
    \text{Inhibitor binding} \\
    \text{Inhibitor dissociation} \\
    \text{RNAP binding} \\
    \text{RNAP dissociation} \\
    \text{Transcription} \\
    \text{Translation} \\
    \text{Conversion} \\
    \text{Inhibitor RNA degradation} \\
    \text{Inhibitor degradation} \\
    \text{Lactose inhibitor degradation} \\
    \text{RNA degradation} \\
    \text{z degradation} \\
     \end{pmatrix}} \\ \]
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\[ Pre = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
Post = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}} \] \\
\[M = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    50 \\
    20 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    100 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
c = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
    0.02 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    0.005 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
    0.01 \\
    0.1 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.03 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    1e-05 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.002 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.001
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
h(x,c) = \scriptsize{\begin{pmatrix}
    c_1i \\
    c_2r_I \\
    c_3ILac \\
    c_4I \cdot Lac \\
    c_5Io \\
    c_6I \cdot o \\
    c_7oRNAP \\
    c_8o \cdot RNAP \\
    c_9o \cdot RNAP \\
    c_{10}r \\
    c_{11}Lacz \\
    c_{12}r_I \\
    c_{13}I \\
    c_{14}I \cdot Lac \\
    c_{15}r \\
    c_{16}Z \\
    \end{pmatrix}}\]

\end{document}
```

Currently this takes up far too much room, and necessarily too as there is a lot of blank space.

Comment: you really don't need to load `amsmath` or `amsthm` (or any package, for that matter) multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into your document there are many errors. In math mode, in order to use a different (smaller) font; or use `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`. Never `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
\ce{i &-> i + r_I, \\
r_i &-> r_I + I, \\
I + Lac &-> I \cdot Lac, \\
I \cdot Lac &-> I + Lac, \\
I + o &-> I \cdot o, \\
I \cdot o &-> I + o, \\
o + RNAP &-> o \cdot RNAP, \\
o \cdot RNAP &-> o + RNAP, \\
o \cdot RNAP &-> o + RNAP + r, \\
r &-> r + Z, \\
Lac + Z &-> Z, \\
r_I &-> \emptyset, \\
I &-> \emptyset, \\
I \cdot Lac &-> Lac, \\
r &-> \emptyset, \\
z &-> \emptyset
}
\end{align*}

where 


\begin{table}[ht]
%\caption{Nonlinear Model Results} % title of Table
\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{c c} % centered columns (4 columns)
\hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Species name & Symbol  \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table
%heading
\hline % inserts single horizontal line
Regulatory gene & $i$ \\ [1ex] % inserting body of the table
Repressor protein & $r_I$ \\ [1ex]
Inhibitor protein & $I$ \\ [1ex]
Lactose & $Lac$ \\ [1ex]
Operator region & $o$ \\ [1ex]
RNA polymerase & $RNAP$ \\ [1ex]
mRNA & $r$ \\ [1ex]
$\beta$-galactosidase & $Z$ \\ [1.5ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
\hline %inserts single line
\end{tabular}
\caption{Lac Operon species}
%\label{table:nonlin} % is used to refer this table in the text
\end{table}



Using SPN theory the system is represented as




\[N \, = \, (P,T,\text{Pre},\text{Post},M,h,c), \quad
 P = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
           i \\
           r_I \\
    I \\
    Lac \\
    I \cdot Lac \\
    o \\
    I \cdot o \\
    RNAP \\
    RNAP \cdot o \\
    r \\
    Z \\
         \end{pmatrix}}
%, \quad
% T = \begin{pmatrix}
%       \text{Enzyme-substrate association} \\
%       \text{Enzyme-substrate dissociation} \\
%       \text{Product formation} \\
%     \end{pmatrix}
 \] \\

\[ T = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
       \text{Inhibitor transcription} \\
       \text{Inhibitor translation} \\
       \text{Lactose inhibitor binding} \\
    \text{Lactose inhibitor dissociation} \\
    \text{Inhibitor binding} \\
    \text{Inhibitor dissociation} \\
    \text{RNAP binding} \\
    \text{RNAP dissociation} \\
    \text{Transcription} \\
    \text{Translation} \\
    \text{Conversion} \\
    \text{Inhibitor RNA degradation} \\
    \text{Inhibitor degradation} \\
    \text{Lactose inhibitor degradation} \\
    \text{RNA degradation} \\
    \text{z degradation} \\
     \end{pmatrix}} \\ \]
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\[ Pre = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\  
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
Post = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}} \] \\
\[M = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    50 \\
    20 \\
    0 \\
    1 \\
    0 \\
    100 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
c = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
    0.02 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    0.005 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    1 \\ 
    0.01 \\
    0.1 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.03 \\ 
    0.1 \\ 
    1e-05 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.002 \\ 
    0.01 \\ 
    0.001
    \end{pmatrix}}, \quad
h(x,c) = \scriptstyle{\begin{pmatrix}
    c_1i \\
    c_2r_I \\
    c_3ILac \\
    c_4I \cdot Lac \\
    c_5Io \\
    c_6I \cdot o \\
    c_7oRNAP \\
    c_8o \cdot RNAP \\
    c_9o \cdot RNAP \\
    c_{10}r \\
    c_{11}Lacz \\
    c_{12}r_I \\
    c_{13}I \\
    c_{14}I \cdot Lac \\
    c_{15}r \\
    c_{16}Z \\
    \end{pmatrix}}\]

\end{document}
```